# Como posso imprimir a quinta parte de um número real?

Tags: c, float, scanf, printf

Como eu poderia imprimir a quinta (índice 4 à partir do ponto) parte de um número real sem usar bibliotecas ou um código "complexo" para capítulos iniciais.

- Faça um programa que leia um número real, e imprima a quinta parte desse número.

Comment: A quinta parte  não seria 1/5 do número?

Comment: Creio que seja o 5 elemento, essas são as únicas informações passadas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
   double entrada, quintaParte;
   printf ("Digite um numero: \n");

   scanf ("%lf", &entrada);

   quintaParte = entrada * 1/5;
   printf ("A quinta parte de %lf eh: \n %lf\n",  entrada, quintaParte);

   return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Em Python seria assim:

```
n = float(input('Digite um número: '))

q = n * (1/5)

print('A quinta parte de {:.2f} é {:.2f}'.format(n, q))
```

Obrigado pela oportunidade.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.

Comment: A questão refere `c` e não `python`